# Hiring company asks for my previous performance reviews and for a recommendation?

Tags: hiring-process, performance-reviews, hiring, recommendation-letter

I had a couple of interviews and people at the company asked me to send them my internal performance reviews and to give them a phone number where they can reach out to a manager with whom I worked in the past.

I don't think it is normal to share internal performance reviews with external companies! Even though I have good ones.

What are typical ways to handle this type of request?

Comment: Can you give some geographical context? What country is this in?

Comment: Just to add to other responses that in some companies managers can be indeed prohibited from providing references, so before you give your (former) manager's contact to the hiring company, speak to him/her. It may turn out that you must give your former company's HR department contact instead.

Comment: I'm with Joe on this, just asking for performance evaluations would be a showstopper for me. I would decline and end the interview. Anyone who doesn't understand the concept of private information is not someone I would consider working for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> give them a phone number where they can reach out to a manager with whom I worked in the past.

It is not uncommon for a reference to be asked for as part of a interview process.

> the company asked me to send them my internal performance reviews

This is uncommon, these are usually very personal and specific. Could you ask them why they need to see these performance reviews? Your performance should be exemplified in your improving work which would be usually highlighted by yourself in a interview.

Answer (score 7):

Getting a recommendation from your previous manager is very normal.

Getting to see your performance reviews from previous jobs is absolutely not normal. Performance reviews often contain private and confidential information, both for you and the company you worked for. You should decline that request, citing that you are forbidden from disclosing information confidential to your previous company.

Answer (score 2):

> What are typical ways to handle this type of request?

I would tell them I don't have these performance reviews and give them a contact of a manager. They can ask the manager for them (and see how far they get).

I would actually be a bit upset if a former manager shared my performance reviews with a third party without my permission.